# returning value before @Async funtion is complete

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, controller

Hi i have a controller who needs to call an other controller and return a value before the other controller finishes.

```
@EnableAsync
@Controller
public class InitController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(InitController.class);
    @Value("${init.hostname}")
    private String base_url;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/init/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String initialize(@PathVariable String id) throws Fault_Exception {
    try {
        Future<String> result = customerAsync(id);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;

    }

    @Async
    private Future<String> customerAsync(String id) throws Fault_Exception, IOException{


        URL url = new URL(base_url + "rest/customer/" + id);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200 ) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        conn.disconnect();
        return new AsyncResult<String>(null);
    }


}
```

Now what happens is that when i call the InitController, it waits before returning null untill the /rest/customer/ controller is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use **aspectj**, Spring will not create proxies for private methods, so in your example, `customerAsync` method is called synchronously.

The easiest way to solve your problem is to extract `customerAsync` method to separate `@Component` annotated class.

Additionally `@EnableAsync` annotation should be used on `@Configuration` class instead of controller.